# Silverlight DataGridDragDropTarget. How to drag a data grid item into a stack panel / user control?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-toolkit

I have a `DataGrid`. I have `DataGridDragDropTarget` from November Toolkit.

I now can drag and drop a data grid item to a listbox or tree view..

However I need to drop the item onto my user control (and add it to a plane stack panel).

There is an article from the guy who wrote all these extension: http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/10/silverlight-drag-drop-support-part-2.html

But he is incomprehensive. Did anyone try to do the similar I need?

**I would like to use a behavior** (custom behavior is fine - I did it before) **or toolkit DragDropTarget solution.**

*I just dont know how to attach to an individual data grid item...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did:

a. the grid is wrapped in:

```
            <dtool:DataGridDragDropTarget msw:DragDrop.AllowDrop="False" ItemDragCompleted="ItemDragCompleted_Handler"
                                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

b. The child user control which is supposed to receive the drop has `MouseEnter` / `MouseLeave` events hooked up and the `IsMouseInside` public property exposed.

c. The event handler as follows:

```
void ItemDragCompleted_Handler(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    if (ChildControl.IsMouseInside)
    {
        SelectionCollection sel = (e.Data as SelectionCollection);
        ChildControl.AddItem(sel[0].Item as MyData);
...
```